# Use attr_accessor to return navigation field value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a belongs_to relation in my Patient model, then I need to create an attr_accessor to read the state_id from the city specified in the Patient object.

How can I do this?

If I just use attr_accessor :state_id, I'd have to set it in the class initialization and the value would be static. I need it to be read only and updated automatically according to the current value of City navigation property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an `attr_accessor` you just need a method.

```
class Patient

  def state_id
    city.state_id
  end

end
```

If the city association is optional you may want to handle the possibility of city being nil...

```
class Patient

  def state_id
    city.try(:state_id)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your API for your `Patient` object to look something like `@patient.state_id`, then either [SteveTurczyn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36610097/567863) or [delegation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) could work for you in order to read the state_id from the city specified in the Patient object:

```
class Patient
  # you can remove `allow_nil` if the patient will *always* have a city
  delegate :state_id, to: :city, allow_nil: true
end
```